How to get VLAN tagging working in MacOS?
I have a 2020 Intel iMac running 14.5 Sonoma with 3 physical Ethernet interfaces, each attached to a switch port on different VLANs (12, 51, and 203). I have a virtual lab set up in VMware Workstation for testing in which all the "server" VMs are running on VLAN 51, and the "workstation" VMs are set up on VLAN 203. All the routes, VLANs, and firewall rules are set up properly on the infrastructure side.
Running Windows in BootCamp, this setup works fine. The VMs configured to run on each NIC can all access other VMs on the same VLAN, and the Internet, but cannot talk across networks or to my host computer (which is the intended design). I accomplished this by configuring VLAN tagging in each NIC's device properties in Windows, and bridging the VMs to whichever NIC I want them to be on.
On the MacOS side however, the VLANs don't work. I created virtual interfaces for each VLAN, but VMs bridged to them have can only communicate with each other on their respective VLANs. I can't ping the router or access the Internet.
How can I get this setup to work in MacOS? I'd rather not have to use BootCamp to work with these VMs.
